# Complex BBCode To HTML Regex With .replace

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to combine these two `.replace` statements into one?

```
.replace(/(\[((size=)(1|2|3|4|5|6))\])/gi, '<font size="$4">')
.replace(/(\[((\/)(size))\])/gi, '</font>')
```

I am not sure if there is a way.

Comment: please provide your input output sample...

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use just 1 regex for it since you have 2 different replacement strings. However, you can capture these tags with 1 regex, and then chain another `replace` method to tranform "bad" `<font>` tag to the closing one.

I presume that there will be no attributes with empty values.

```js
var re = /\[\/?size(?:=([1-6]))?\]/gi; 
var str = '[size=6][/size]';
var subst = '<font size="$1">'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst).replace(/<font size="">/, "</font>");
// Now, just display
document.getElementById("res").value = result;
```

```html
<input id="res"/>
```

Comment: The capturing groups are quite excessive here. Should be possible to reduce to just `/\[\/?size(?:=([1-6]))?\]/gi`

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, possible, we just never know what OP really wants to do with them later. Thus, I tend to keep to original ones.

Comment: Actually, capturing the backslash `(\/?)` make sense if you use a replacement function to evaluate whether it is open tag or close tag to replace accordingly, rather than this hack-ish solution where you replace the failed open tag replacement with close tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this single regex:**

```
var re = /\[(size)=(\d{1,6})\]([^\[]+)\[\/size\]/gi;
var str = '[size=2]dd\n[/size]';
var subst = '<font size="$2">$3</font>';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

regex expain:
`\[(size)=`              //capture `[`, `size` and `=`

`(\d{1,6})\]`              //capture size number and `]`

`([^\[]+)`              //capture between `[size=3]`  and `[/size]`

`\[\/size\]`         //capture `[/size]`

```js
var re = /\[(size)=(\d{1,6})\]([^\[]+)\[\/size\]/gi;
var str = '[size=2]dd\n[/size]';
var subst = '<font size="$2">$3</font>';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);

$("#b").val(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" style="width:100%" id="b" />
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC3xH5/4)

Comment: I like the way your answer is written. The idea of just using 1 regex to match opening and close tags is good, but what if they are not in the same input string? Perhaps, that is the main problem here.